# Using Google API to find if a company has a website

Tags: google-maps, web-crawler, google-places-api, google-crawlers

I am looking for a solution that would tell me if a particular company has a website. The way I imagine using it is: I would send a phrase-based query to the API (for example "Salesforce Limited") and it would return a website if it has one in its database).

I checked Google Maps API and Google Places API but can's see if they provide website addresses for places.

I know Google displays a location on the right hand side if you type a name of the place and at times also has a website link referring to it:

[example data I am after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOhnm.jpg)

Do you know if the website data can be accessed by any of the Google APIs and if not what could be an alternative way of obtaining such data?

Thanks
Kam

Comment: The [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) you get from the Places API  includes a website